# Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.17.0 and appid/appsecret

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, adal

When upgrading from v3.16.1 to v3.17.0 of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` I cannot find an overload on how to aquire an access token using an ADAL app with `clientId` and `clientSecret` which I previously could pass in as a `ClientCredential` object.

The below overload of `AcquireTokenAsync` is no longer present, so what would the approach be going forward?

```
var clientCredential = new ADAL.ClientCredential(AppId, AppSecret);
var token = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphResourceId, clientCredential);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AcquireTokenAsync` is in the class `AuthenticationContextConfidentialClientExtensions` and still able to use. Please refer the code below([source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/3982cb2886d8b6e561d890e749eb932a55439145/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/Features/WinCommon/AuthenticationContextConfidentialClientExtensions.cs#L337L350)):

```
/// <summary>
/// Acquires security token from the authority.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ctx">Authentication context instance</param>
/// <param name="resource">Identifier of the target resource that is the recipient of the requested token.</param>
/// <param name="clientCredential">The client credential to use for token acquisition.</param>
/// <returns>It contains Access Token and the Access Token's expiration time. Refresh Token property will be null for this overload.</returns>
public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(this AuthenticationContext ctx,
    string resource, ClientCredential clientCredential)
{
    return await ctx.AcquireTokenForClientCommonAsync(resource, new ClientKey(clientCredential))
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Please check it and feel free to let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: Seems it all worked again after a cleanup of using statements, so it's indeed there :)